# image in wordpress not resizable, it works on other platforms though

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have webpage in wordpress where I have writte some code already. On the right of the webpage I have the images stored. I want them to have a width of 300px but it seems it is not working when I change the width or whatever.

I think the images has a random size at the moment because of wordpress. In other platforms like jsfiddle I can change the size without a problem.

The image size is only changing when I move the image, and it looks really bad that way. When I want to change .imageright to 500 px, nothing is changing. 
Anyone know what the solution may be ?

plnkr : https://plnkr.co/edit/5HQy89zapAVysoVDS06Z?p=preview  (best to view in full page)

wordpress:  http://giscience.zgis.at/de/concept-projekte-page/

```
<style>
  .Capital {
    margin: 0px 0 -5px 0;
    line-height: 63px;
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: ligter;
  }

  .smalltext {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    font-weight: 100px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .square {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #73B7DB;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  .left {
    width: 30%;
    margin: 05% 00% 00% 05%;
  }

  .container {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
  }

  .paragraphs {
    margin: 5% 10% 2% 00%;
    width: 40%;
  }

  .right {
    width: 30%;
    float: right;
    margin: 02% 00% 0% 00%;
  }

  .imageright {
    width: 300px;
  }
</style>






<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="square"><span class="Capital">M</span>
      <br><span class="smalltext">Methods</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="paragraphs">

    Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem
    IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <img class="imageright" src="http://ideaslab.sbg.ac.at/ideaslab/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/why300x200-300dpi.jpg" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress automatically resizes images. When you have embedded that in to your post, you have selected Medium (300px) or something similar (if you look at image URL in Wordpress frontend you will see on the URL it is not original.

If you edit the image from the post editor there is an option called Image Size in there. Set that to full size and it will be the original image that should respect your CSS.

You can set default resize sizes in Settings -> Media.

Comment: The problem is that even if the picture has a real width of 16 pixels, the image should have a 300 pixels width, regarding the CSS code. This is not a problem from *WordPress* images modification, but more a problem related to code and stylesheets loading.

Comment: Yea so far all the things I have tried didnt work so far. Maybe remove imageright will work :S

Answer (score 0):

Applying custom style in *WordPress* can be tricky, since it all depends on when the stylesheets of your *WordPress* theme are loaded.

To know if your `width : 300px;` on `.imageright` has been successfully applied or not, just press F12 while your on your browser, and check for all the properties that this image have.

- If you can see this line overlined, this means the properties has been overwrited by another one called after yours.
- If you can't see your line, this means your `<style>` is not applied. You can try to access your *WordPress* theme's CSS files and add your class in it, to be sure that it will be called, but this will imply some themes modifications which can have consequences on other elements on your website, so be carefull with this solution.

I hope this will help you.